# Can a bounded and a NON monotonic succession converge?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Being $\{a_n\}_{n\in N }$ a succession of real numbers which is bounded and NOT monotonic, can the succesion converge?

To answer the question I must find one succesion $a_n$ that converges, For example:

$$a_n = (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Which converges, is bounded and is not monotonic (as far as I know) then the answer to the question is YES?

Comment: The question is if the succesion CAN converge, not that every succession which is bounded and is not monotonic will converge. $(-1)^n$ surely doesnt converge and is bounded and not monotonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Since the question is whether a certain thing **can** happen and since you found a situation in which that thing **does** happen, the answer is affirmative.